# Algumas barrinhas de erro não aparecem em gráfico do "sciplot"

Tags: r

Está acontecendo um problema quando estou fazendo um gráfico de médias no R usando o pacote "sciplot". Para começar, este é o código de uma parte do meu conjunto de dados:

```
dados <- structure(list(Dias = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("0", 
"3", "6", "9", "12", "15", "18", "21", "24", "27", "30"), class = "factor"), 
    Tratamento = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("Alagado", "Controle"), class = "factor"), 
    Var = c(0.483954721, 0.402513452, 0.512025757, 0.344985618, 
    0.418409264, 0.418409264, 0.511319767, 0.543889494, 0.246440891, 
    0.302144414, 0.34349692, 0.479154807, 0.34349692, 0.34349692, 
    0.415664423, 0.223458159, 0.250861003, 0.434646743, 0.34349692, 
    0.257196387, 0.540148383, 0.517620793, 0.447490544, 0.287040092, 
    0.174128921, 0.489415586, 0.568275611, 0.39165419, 0.529013636, 
    0.374811179, 0.369840511, 0.559673798, 0.506560116, 0.252093219, 
    0.473819853, 0.563274295, 0.532371759, 0.258446375, 0.482760493, 
    0.385915684, 0.40587382, 0.394261898, 0.570618986, 0.418202774, 
    0.342299789, 0.481900239, 0.39861235, 0.378118216, 0.310233914, 
    0.358616211, 0.364058679, 0.395026017, 0.305758233, 0.497028634, 
    0.498580504, 0.245504252, 0.265180056, 0.348491714, 0.216797337, 
    0.348491714, 0.352196, 0.31906076, 0.329692909, 0.434979622, 
    0.412968366, 0.336259781, 0.394290597, 0.391050623, 0.280468087, 
    0.270996386, 0.289080223, 0.351599493, 0.289080223, 0.237839736, 
    0.289080223, 0.423445676, 0.195595218, 0.360309076, 0.289080223, 
    0.165692143, 0.466055527, 0.498216599, 0.612262951, 0.457407711, 
    0.402567153, 0.432520596, 0.446234159, 0.433097588, 0.479705616, 
    0.334278466, 0.220010369, 0.375294032, 0.574471328, 0.377909951, 
    0.34732317, 0.347616995, 0.270351352, 0.477391563, 0.371043001, 
    0.373490196, 0.256574725, 0.298053469, 0.322380312, 0.287292048, 
    0.212319809, 0.24631103, 0.176862546, 0.141438726, 0.242654083, 
    0.242654083, 0.142837656, 0.175949172, 0.175949172, 0.158684528, 
    0.122141631, 0.175949172, 0.164364339, 0.11907127, 0.175949172, 
    0.175949172, 0.283410497, 0.278052602, 0.263745, 0.262582543, 
    0.244684158, 0.263745, 0.263745, 0.263745, 0.263745, 0.263745, 
    0.211983691, 0.036175954, 0.124079823, 0.124079823, 0.124079823, 
    0.124079823, 0.124079823, 0.124079823, 0.124079823, 0.124079823, 
    0.541883571, 0.425976278, 0.472908724, 0.462862966, 0.491197094, 
    0.440611376, 0.553310475, 0.535958712, 0.479224575, 0.388311983, 
    0.337605, 0.337290226, 0.337605, 0.360191501, 0.159098255, 
    0.212415407, 0.445623893, 0.485658868, 0.343586622, 0.416791451, 
    0.466813153, 0.530845846, 0.563399265, 0.446772564, 0.341090484, 
    0.440579265, 0.440579265, 0.440579265, 0.358498545, 0.376635, 
    0.0362885, 0.038825342, 0.069852283, 0.057607035, 0.061824905, 
    0.0454871, 0.061824905, 0.074349388, 0.039976409, 0.064498082, 
    0.204017899, 0.212166919, 0.232099119, 0.20038374, 0.212166919, 
    0.212166919, 0.212166919, 0.212166919, 0.212166919, 0.212166919, 
    0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 
    0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 0.034938801, 
    0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 
    0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 0.384175286, 
    0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242, 
    0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242, 0.049557242
    )), row.names = c(NA, -220L), class = "data.frame")
```

Em seguida, executo os seguintes códigos:

```
dados$Dias <- as.factor(dados$Dias)
str(dados)

library(sciplot)

#Gráfico
lineplot.CI(dados$Dias, dados$Var, group = dados$Tratamento, las = 1,
xlab = "Time (days)",
ylab = "Var",
err.width = 0.1, bty = "l")
```

Na sequência, aparece essas mensagens de aviso e o gráfico:

```
Warning messages:
1: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
2: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
3: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
  zero-length arrow is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já pesquisei bastante em diferentes sites o significado desses avisos, mas não encontrei uma resposta satisfatória para a minha situação. É possível perceber que os dois últimos pontos da classe "alagado" e o último de "controle" não possuem as barrinhas de erro. Alguém saberia dizer o que pode estar acontecendo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O warning dá uma boa ideia do que está acontecendo (grifos meus):

> Warning messages:
>
> 1: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
>   **zero-length arrow** is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
>
> 2: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
>   **zero-length arrow** is of indeterminate angle and so skipped
>
> 3: In arrows(leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln], CI.plot[, 1], leg.vals$xvals[CI.seln],  :
>   **zero-length arrow** is of indeterminate angle and so skipped

Há barras de comprimento zero. Como estas barras representam a variabilidade dos dados, provavelmente há casos em que não há variabilidade neles. Dá pra verificar isso com o código abaixo:

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>%
  group_by(Dias, Tratamento) %>%
  summarise(desvPad = sd(Var)) %>%
  arrange(desvPad)
## # A tibble: 22 x 3
## # Groups:   Dias [11]
##    Dias  Tratamento desvPad
##    <fct> <fct>        <dbl>
##  1 27    Alagado    0      
##  2 30    Alagado    0      
##  3 30    Controle   0      
##  4 27    Controle   0.00818
##  5 18    Controle   0.0102 
##  6 24    Alagado    0.0138 
##  7 15    Alagado    0.0228 
##  8 18    Alagado    0.0414 
##  9 21    Controle   0.0534 
## 10 15    Controle   0.0549 
## # … with 12 more rows
```

Perceba que as combinações de dias e tratamentos que não possuem barras de erro no gráfico são justamente aquelas em que a variabilidade é zero. Conferindo o conjunto de dados para o dia 30, vemos que isso é verdade.

```
dados %>%
  filter(Dias == 30)
##    Dias Tratamento        Var
## 1    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 2    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 3    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 4    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 5    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 6    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 7    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 8    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 9    30   Controle 0.38417529
## 10   30   Controle 0.38417529
## 11   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 12   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 13   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 14   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 15   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 16   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 17   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 18   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 19   30    Alagado 0.04955724
## 20   30    Alagado 0.04955724
```

Portanto, estas barras de erro nunca vão aparecer utilizando este conjunto de dados.